# load img in div on button click - Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Im using a wordpress site and am trying to load an image (tracking pixel) when a link is clicked. I have this code but does not seem to load. Am i missing anything? Thanks in advance for the help.

HTML

```
<a class="button" target="_blank" title="" href="/rd/credit-check.php" id="ccBtn"><span class="fusion-button-text">GET YOUR FREE CREDIT SCORES NOW!</span></a>
 <div id="pixel"></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery("#ccBtn").click(function(){
jQuery("#pixel").html("<img src='http://imageurl.com/img.png' alt='itworks' />");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a timing issue. The browser must be fetching the link faster than the image has time to load.

I would alter the jQuery to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#ccBtn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //stop click
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.off('click'); //remove this function when click on link
        $("#pixel").html("<img src='http://imageurl.com/img.png' alt='itworks' />"); //add image
        setTimeout(function(){$this.trigger('click')}, 500); //click on this link again.
    });
});
```

This stops the link from firing for half a second while the pixel is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is an image load time problem like other members have mentioned, let me be the first to mention a great plugin by David DeSandro called [ImagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/).

Once it is implemented in your site you can at any point in time ask it to respond to any container fully loading its images and then complete a callback function.

Then you can do the answer given here by @nicael

Like so....

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $("#someDiv").imagesLoaded(function() {
        $("#ccBtn").click(function(){
            $("#pixel").html("<img src='http://imageurl.com/img.png' alt='itworks' />");
        });
    });
});
```

This would allow you to load all images before attempting to bind an event listener to it.

Comment: thanks for the tip, in this case it's a tracking pixel that needs to load to track a conversion